# In the context of PCA and random projection, what does $\tilde{X} \sim XR$ mean?

Tags: projection, data-mining

In the context of PCA and random projection, what does $\tilde{X} \sim XR$ mean?

The projection seems to generally be defined as $\tilde{X} = XR$, but what does the tilde do there?

Comment: Generally, $\sim$ means "is distributed as". So when you write $Y\sim N(0,1)$, you mean $Y$ has the standard normal distribution. So they are saying $\tilde X$ has the same distribution as $XR$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Seems somewhat reasonable, since $R$ is a random matrix (i.e. I assume it contains or is generated using some sort of probabilities).